# Jmeter - I am trying to login with multiple in jmeter, but the there are more than 1 format of token, How can I handle get token

Tags: authentication, jmeter

I'm send a http request to receive a token. But I find that I receive from response 2 format of token randomly.
First format is: [First format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipG42.png)
The token is between % and %3d

Second format is: [Second format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAHIi.png)
The token is between %3d and %3d but remove %2

So how I need help to handle 2 of format?

I'm tried to find solution for using If/else for Regular Expression Extractor but I cannot find it
Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's something to do with [URL encoding](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP)?

For example

- `%3d` stands for `=`
- `%2` is not correct, there should be one more character, for example `%20` is a whitespace

[image]

Take a look at [__urldecode() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urldecode), my expectation is that it should help you to deal with the "different formats"

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions)